# Leaflet symbology using jQuery with a static api response

Tags: leaflet, javascript, api, jquery

I'm symbolizing a road network by getting a response from a static api.
I have a GeoJSON loaded on the frontend that contains **XDSegID** as the primary key. I'm sending an AJAX request which returns **XDSegID** and its **value** against it. Then I'm looping through the response and assigning style properties for each value while matching their IDs.

The problem is that the loop consumes a lot of time to complete and then data is displayed on the frontend. I'm looking for an alternative approach where I would load all the data on map refresh and then use it to change symbology without having to loop through the ID's every time the data is requested. I can't think of any ways of storing the symbology that I could pass to leaflet for "setStyle" to work.

Some code example would be helpful. My current code is shared below:

```
$(".ambtn").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        method:"get",
        url:"/los_am",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#loader").css({
            display: "inline-block",
            visibility: "visible"
            });
        },
        complete: function(){
            $("#loader").css({
                display: "none",
                visibility: "hidden"
            });
        },
        success:function(res){
            // console.log(res)
            rdNetworkLyr.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                for (const key in res.XDSegID){
                    if(res.XDSegID.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                        if(layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'A'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#060'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'B'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#9f0'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'C'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#ff3'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'D'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#f90'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'E'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#f60'})
                        }
                        else if (layer.feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'F'){
                            layer.setStyle({color:'#c00'})
                        }
                    }
                }
              });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that each AJAX call `$.ajax({method:"get",url:"/los_am",...` returns the same result? If not, what exactly do you mean by "I would load all the data on map refresh"? What is "map refresh" here and how/when does it happen?

Comment: Yes, each call returns the same result. By map refresh, I mean when the application loads or the page is refreshed, it would send a one time request to the server and store it.

Comment: Then just store result of your AJAX call in some global object and then use it as source data for styling features.

Comment: I tried storing it in a global variable but the actual time consumption happens when the loop is run. I'm aiming to run a loop only once, store its results somehow and then pass them to the setStyle function.

Comment: So you are saying that also content of `rdNetworkLyr` layer is not changing? So you just want to change the style upon click, and style is based on static data?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

On possible solution to quickly change style of features would be:

- first read AJAX data and upon completion create vector layer `rdNetworkLyr` and within `onEachFeature` function assign secondary color as property of the feature;
- define some global boolean variable `secondaryStyleActive` which tells that secondary style is in use;
- in style function for `rdNetworkLyr` layer check if secondary style is in use; if so, return color assigned as feature property, otherwise primary color;
- in click processing function negate value of `secondaryStyleActive` and then reassign style to `rdNetworkLyr` layer, so that new value of `secondaryStyleActive` will be taken into account.

Code could then look something like this:

```
let secondaryStyleActive = false;

function rdNetworkStyle(feature) {
  let style = secondaryStyleActive ? feature.properties.color : '#aaaaaa';
  return style;
}

let rdNetworkLyr;

$.ajax({
  method:"get",
  url:"/los_am",
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#loader").css({
      display: "inline-block",
      visibility: "visible"
    });
  },
  complete: function() {
    $("#loader").css({
      display: "none",
      visibility: "hidden"
    });
  },
  success: function(res) {
    rdNetworkLyr = L.geoJSON(data, {
      style: rdNetworkStyle,
      onEachFeature: function(feature) {
        for (const key in res.XDSegID){
          if(res.XDSegID.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'A'){
              feature.properties.color = '#060';
            }
            else if (feature.properties.XDSegID === res.XDSegID[key] && res.los[key] === 'B'){
              feature.properties.color = '#9f0';
            }
            else if ....
          }
        }
      }
    });
});

$(".ambtn").on("click",function() {
  secondaryStyleActive = !secondaryStyleActive;
  rdNetworkLyr.setStyle(rdNetworkStyle);
});
```